# IVR Integration with that of vendor IVR system | SSO Implementation

Tags: java, single-sign-on, ivr

all.

I am working in IVR development. My current project has a requirement to Integrate our IVR with that of the vendor's IVR system.

Scenario:

For the IVR portal, there would be a new functionality to make the payments through phone over the IVR. All the payment transaction is handled by a different vendor named "PaymentsMasterInc".

Currently, the flow is when the member dials in a certain number IVR asks account credential information i.e. account id, DOB and the authentication pin, once user is authenticated he/she can lookup the account info. With the new functionality there would be a new option, by choosing which the member can make the payment over the phone.

As soon the user chooses this option, the call need to be transferred over to the vendor's IVR system along with the the user's account info(account#, DOB and the pin ) so that the vendor IVR know which member is about to make the payment and the end caller need not to pass the account information again.

Any thoughts on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to provide more detailed information on the IVR and telephony systems involved to provide any detailed solution. But in general you could use a cloud-based computer-telephony-integration (CTI). The CTI will need to integrate in with the telephony system/switch on the IVR that receives the transfer.  For this discussion we will call the IVR that initially receives the call IVR A and the one that receives the transfer and handles payment is IVR B.  The telephony system on the IVR B side will need a DNIS pool.  The number of DNIS's in the pool depends on the expected traffic volumes during peak times.  The basic steps are:

1. When IVR A is ready to transfer it makes a request to IVR B's CTI component that it is ready to make a transfer. At the time of the request it will send the data that IVR B needs (ex: account #, DOB, pin...).
2. The CTI component responds back that it is ready to receive the call and what DNIS to use.
3. IVR A transfers the call to the DNIS provided by the CTI component. When the CTI component  recognizes a call on that DNIS it takes the associated data and passes it to IVR B on the port that the call is sent to.

These CTI components need to be tightly integrated with the specif telephony system/switch used.  Building these components from scratch is a rather large job and you may want to look at an off-the-shelf solution.  Companies like Chrysalis Software and the major  telephony providers usually have these types of solutions available.

This solution can work for TDM and VoIP. But if you are using VoIP there are other techniques for transferring data directly with the call.  If you are not experienced with CTI I would recommend getting the assistance of a knowledgeable systems integrator.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I appreciate your inputs on this.

So for this to happen, IVR A should have the direct access to the IVR B CTI  component. WHich I need to discuss with the Vendor(IVR B)

Aditionally, once IVR A recieves the DNIS from IVR B's CTI component, the call would be transferred through the PBX at the IVR A side. Would the ACD be able enough to send the call to IVR B and on reception of the call, IVR B will be able to recognize the call and the associated data?

Comment: Most PBX/ACD's should be able handle directing traffic to an IVR and with a CTI component integrated with the switch and IVR, the IVR would be able to get the associated data. I have done this before with Avaya and Nortel switches.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Is there any specific CTI components that has the ability to connect with the PBX/ACD's directly?

We are using Pega BlueLyncs and that doesn't integrate directly with ACD, I think.

Comment: It looks like Pega BlueLyncs provides screen pops into legacy health care systems. It may use some other CTI component under the hood to provide that functionality. What ACD are you using?

Comment: Not sure exactly about ACD but all the telephony equipments are Avaya products. And yes the CTI component is CTC Netmerge.

Comment: Check out Chrysalis [http://www.chrysalis.net/]. They have a product called CloudBurst that integrates with Avaya, they are an Avaya partner, and they have CTC and systems integration experience.

Comment: One more thing. How to pass the data from the IVR to ACD. i.e. when the IVR transfers the call to ACD, how it should transfer the data packets i.e. Accountnumber and DOB with a hash delimiter.

Comment: The data will be passed via the CTI's API.  The API will be specific to the vendors product. But most modern products use web services (i.e HTTP) as the transport mechanism.

Comment: Ok, let me reiterate again, the vendor IVR (with which I need to make the integration) only accepts the data in a hash delimited values and IVR  A in case of transfer does the blind transfer and only pass the extension number to the ACD.

Now to support the integration with IVR B, The ACD at IVR A has to pass the data packets via DTMF to IVR B. 

So now the question is how IVR A would pass the data along with extension number to ACD at IVR A?

Comment: What you are describing is an in-band integration where the data is passed as DTMF. This is extremely limiting in what you can pass to IVR B. What I was describing is an out-of-band integration where the data is sent via a data network using TCP/IP/HTTP, which is the preferred method. I am assuming that you are using TDM, not VoIP. If you are stuck with in-band integration then you can try doing a supervised transfer to IVR B, and when it answers send the DTMF that represents the acccount num and DOB.  You send the DTMF by stringing together recordings of DTMF. Then conference caller and drop.

Comment: Hi Kevin, THanks much for your assistance. The same approach vendor suggested me to follow but I am not pretty sure how to make that change. I mean how to make a conference and when to drop a call. 

I would appreciate if you can please enlighten me step-by-step procedure. Thanks..!!

Comment: I would appreciate if you can please throw some light on it. If you have any reference code that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I have not had to do an in-band integration in years and any code would be very specific to the IVR platform and development tools.